# What's the difference in usage and nuance between やはり and やっぱり?

Tags: nuances

I know that we say にっぽん instead of にほん when we want to inject a little national pride into the word, but I've never had a good understanding of the difference in meaning/nuance/usage between やはり and やっぱり.

I would guess that there is some variation in some combination of politeness, formality, familiarity etc, but I haven't had enough experiences with them to pin down where they sit on that graph.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

やっぱり「矢っ張り」 is a bit stronger in sense than やはり「矢張り」, but most of the time, it is a personal preference.

There are some more versions of やはり like

やっぱし、やっぺし、やっぴし、and also やっぱ is widely used.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the stronger sense.  That would make sense why I don't hear やっぱり used to superiors.

Comment: 「やっぺし」「やっぴし」って・・・? 若者言葉ですか、それとも方言ですかね・・・。

Comment: [やっぴし](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/222209/meaning/m0u/)は近世語のようです。やっぺしは東北方言（？）で、たぶんこれは「やるべし」の転なので、どちらも意味が違うと思いますね。

Answer (score 16):

やはり is more formal (e.g. appropriate for superiors & business).  People say やっぱり all the time, including in business.

Written scholarly works would most certainly use やはり.  Shibuya gals would most certainly use やっぱり.  There's a wide range in between.

Comment: +1 During very formal speeches, for instance at conferences, the speaker does not use やっぱり, always やはり.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.