# Difference between めっちゃくちゃ and めちゃくちゃ

Tags: grammar, meaning, pronunciation

Yesterday I saw the movie "Atelier", and I heard the phrase め**っ**ちゃくちゃ. Is it grammatically correct? And how to translate it?

Can emphasized め**っ**ちゃくちゃ be found in official literature? Google shows about 999,000 results.. And めちゃくちゃ - 42,900,000 results.

Can someone answer it, not just give a down-votes? I will not give up :)

Comment: Yes, almost the answer, thanks. What is the history of this phrase? How it is derived/composed?

Comment: This [dictionary entry](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%81%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83) should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that the version with っ is more emotive and/or emphatic. This is not unique to めっちゃ:

- [やはり→やっぱり](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/418/542)
- [とても→とっても](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/808/542)

It is more emotive and it closes the distance between the speaker and listener. If the speaker was in an official or a formal role such as a person giving a speech at a conference or addressing an important person, the use of the emotive version causes the speaker to be perceived as representing his personal self instead of representing his official post or role at that time. As such it may be unsuitable for formal use, and hence may possibly be perceived as rude or impolite for being incongruent with the social situation at hand.

Answer (score 3):

Today, some young Japanese people often use the word "めっちゃ" in informal situation. It means "very" (or "quite", "totally", "extremely", and so on).

They sometimes repeat "っ" in "めっちゃ" for more emphasis. "めっっっちゃ楽しかった！" means "It was very very very fun!". Maybe this usage is not on the any Japanese syntax books, but can be understand by most Japanese people.

Probably, "めっちゃ" comes from "めちゃくちゃ（滅茶苦茶）". I have never seen the word "めっちゃくちゃ". But I can understand it like "めっちゃ", as emphasizing "めちゃくちゃ".[image]

Answer (score 1):

while the (linked) weblio entry is obviously (and almost exhaustively, not to say exhaustingly) correct….   in my experience the word is used colloquially almost similarly to　すごい　or 　とてもとても   as in 景色はめちゃくちゃ奇麗　　or    パーティーはめちゃくちゃ楽しかった　　　and the degree of emphasis placed on it by the speaker also affects the degree of meaning, as with any language…   think about how many intonations you can put on the word 'yes', each of them adding a different nuance….   all very びみょう…     but fun….

Comment: I still don't know if めっちゃくちゃ is grammatically correct.  めちゃくちゃ is ok, but can emphasized  めっちゃくちゃ be found in official literature?

Comment: @Ernestas Gruodis めっちゃくちゃ is grammatically correct; however, in official literature (i.e. 文語), this emphasized version is considered to be 口語 and should be avoided.  The original めちゃくちゃ should be used in its place, similiar to とっても/とても  and やっぱり/やはり.

Comment: Interestingly, the word `めっちゃ` seems to be used much more often than `めちゃ`.

Comment: I came here to understand usage of "めっちゃくちゃ" in spoken language and I think in cases like "景色はめっちゃくちゃ綺麗", it is being used to indicate "very". Thanks for mentioning that.